# Array Index Out of Bounds for Dynamic Programming code

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class Dynamic_Programming {

public static int HowManyWays(int n)
{
    int [] mem = new int[]{0,1};
    for(int i = 2; i <= n; i++)
    {
        int sum = 0;
        for(int k =1; k <= n-1; k++)
        {
            sum += mem[k]*mem[n-k];
        }
        mem[i] = sum;
    }
    return mem[n];
}

public static void main (String [] args)
{
    long startTime = System.nanoTime();
    System.out.println("For 2 matracies: " + HowManyWays(2));
    long totalTime = System.nanoTime()-startTime;
    System.out.println("Time in nanoseconds: " + totalTime);
}
```

}

This is the code for a simple method that uses the dynamic programming technique in order to determine the number of ways to multiply n matrices together. However I keep getting and `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error when I run the program. It tells me that the problem is with this line of code right here. `mem[i] = sum;`. Some guidance on how to fix this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your `mem` stores sum at index 2.  Why you are starting loop from 2 ??

Comment: When `i = 2`, you're trying to set `mem[2] = sum`, but `mem` only has a size of 2 (`mem[0]` and `mem[1]`).

Comment: mem[i] = sum; 
//This statement is throwing Exception , reason is the array size is 2 {arr[0] and arr[1]} as index of array starts from 0 and the statement 
 
    mem[i] = sum; which means at i index of mem array assign value of sum , but i is initialized as 2 , 

  which means you are trying mem[2]=sum , which doesn't exist

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I don't know why I didn't see that sooner.

Answer (score 0):

You only have two elements in your array. Arrays start at 0. When mem[i] is referenced it is trying to invoke the element in the array at index i. Since i = 2 in this case it will take throw an exception.